# Float left in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing an assignment on java script and here were my task

> b. (18 points) Function showRides(): Figure 2
>
> > 1. Create a function that will write the ride’s names, pictures, & information to >the webpage.
> > 2. Remove the HTML that created this information from the rides page.
> > 3. Make sure the JavaScript writes this information to the correct spot – rides.html.

I have created the function in javascript and it works but for the life of me I cannot figure out to get my images to float left. Here is my code in java script:

```
document.write("<a href='images/rhinecruise.jpg'><img id = 'rr' src='images/rhinecruise.jpg' alt='Rhine River Cruise Thumb' style='width:150px;height:113px;'> </a>");
            document.write("<h3>Rhine River Cruise</h3>");
            document.write("<p>Enjoy our fabulous landscaping and other wonderful sites on a relaxing and scenic cruise that showcases the beauty of the 100 acres of Busch Gardens.</p>");
```

And here is where I have called the function in my html:

```
<script>
showrides();
</script>
<br class="clear">
```

Am I suppose to make another function in the java script to make it float left or would I have to change something in the html?

Comment: Are you allowed to use css to do the styling? i.e. float

Comment: can't you just modify the `style` attribute in that `img`? `style='width:150px;height:113px;float:left;'`

Comment: Yes I think we are allowed to use css.

Comment: @Michael I tried that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This looks like homework. Why don't you try to make it float left.

Comment: @AmberB works for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VpdjXB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [**`cssFloat`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_cssfloat.asp) style property:

```
function floatLeft() {
    document.getElementById("rr").style.cssFloat = "left";
}
```

Alternatively, you could just set the `style` directly on the image tag:

```
<img style='float: left;'>
document.write("<a href='images/rhinecruise.jpg'><img id = 'rr' src='images/rhinecruise.jpg' alt='Rhine River Cruise Thumb' style='width:150px;height:113px;float:left;'></a>");
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add the `float:left` property in your `style` attribute, to float it left.

Like this:

```
document.write("<a href='images/rhinecruise.jpg'><img id = 'rr' src='images/rhinecruise.jpg' alt='Rhine River Cruise Thumb' style='width:150px;height:113px; float:left;'> </a>");
```